# Upload file via channel form

Tags: channel-form

I am trying to set up a form on the front-end with channel:form but it doesnt behave.

[channel-form-file-upload http://supinum.com/bilder/channel-form-file-upload.png](http://supinum.com/bilder/channel-form-file-upload.png)

Clicking the 'Undo Remove'-link or the 'close-x' on the thumbnail does nothing but add a # to url.

What is this form lacking? Javascript? css? query? ACTurl-something?

This works perfectly on a simple local install. There I can reproduce this error by unchecking 'Generate HTTP Page Headers?' in 'Output and Debugging Preferences' But doing this backwards doesnt help me on the more complex live site.

What should I look for?

/thanks, David

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>upload files</title>
</head>
<body>
{exp:channel:form channel="formchannel" return="thank/you"}
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        Title<br /><input name="title" type="text">
        Photo<br />{field:photo}
    </div>
</div>

{/exp:channel:form}

</body>
</html>
```

#### Screendump of error message in Safari:

[Screendump of error message in Safari http://supinum.com/bilder/channel_form_error_log.png](http://supinum.com/bilder/channel_form_error_log.png)

Comment: I would start from console and check if there are any js errors, then I would check if you included all assets necesarry for Forms to work

Comment: Thanks. reading and understanding the console is an area I yet have to cover. But viewing the sourse in Safari showed an errorlog complaining about a faulty reference to safecracker. Thats strange. I am running EE271. There should be no safecracker. I checked the third_pary-folders for remains thereof but found nothing.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the JS errors in the console. I might be able lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi! I uploaded a screenshot. See if it gives a hint. It mentions Safecracker but I cant see any traces of Safecracker in my install.

Comment: The error on the left side there (cannot find variable $) would indicate that jQuery is not loaded. Looking in the code a little bit, it looks like the {AID:Channel:combo_loader variable isn't parsing, which is the action ID that would be loading jQuery.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that I moved the system-folder out of the web-root? And that I am trying to use config-overrides in a larger amount than I'm used to. Is there a config-override I could use to guide the form to the query-folder?

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with the 2.7 upgrade not deleting Safecracker properly.

First, check the Modules and Extensions areas of the control panel. If you see Safecracker there, make sure it is uninstalled / disabled.

Then look in system/expressionengine/modules directory and see if there is a safecracker directory. After completing the steps above, you can safely remove that directory.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks for chiming in. I cant find anything safecracker in either (CP or folder structure) Addons/modules, Addons/extensions, ExpressionEngine/modules or ExpressionEngine/extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this solved by Jeremy Worboys on another thread ([Can I see the most basic example of a File field in Channel Form (Safecracker)?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/can-i-see-the-most-basic-example-of-a-file-field-in-channel-form-safecracker)). I had WYGWAM Entries installed, which created a button that caused a fatal JS error. (Repaired it via the exp_html_buttons table.) THEN my jQuery was too high of a version; downgrading to 1.8.3 fixed the visual abnormalities ("x" not working, for example).